# Uniqueness of l1 minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Is it true that $$\min \limits_{Q}|I - QA|_{\infty} < \frac{1}{2}$$ is criteria for the uniqueness of the solution to

$\min \limits_{x \text{ s.t.} Ax=y} |x|_1$ for any $y$.
If yes, where can I read about this result. I am not sure that I have got the criteria correctly.

Update. $|M|_{\infty} = \max \limits_{i,j} |M_{ij}|$

Comment: This seems strange as it implies that there is a matrix $Q$ so that $QA\in\Bbb R^{n×n}$ is invertible, has full rank $n$.  That requires $m\ge n$, so that there are more equations than variables. This would give a minimal-residuum problem, not a minimal-solution-vector problem.

Comment: Why would QA be invertible?

Comment: By the Neumann series, if $\|T\|<1$ in some sub-multiplicative operator norm, then $I-T$ is invertible with the converging series $I+\sum_{k\ge 1} T^k$ as inverse. Here $T=I-QA$ and the norm is the row-sum norm.

Comment: Max norm ($| . |_\infty$) is not submultiplicative

Comment: Then you should mention that it is the component-wise maximum, not the operator norm to the vector max norm.